# Exposed Filter Drupal 6 not working on own theme, worked well on basic theme

Tags: drupal, view, drupal-exposed-filter

I have created a Drupal 6 website. The websites works good but, today I'm trying integrate a filter option for my products in my view. But i have a problem with that. The Exposed filter worked well on the default theme from Drupal and it's working also in the preview. But it doesn't work in my own created theme based on Zenn.

I have realy no idea why it doesn't work. Maby I missing something in my template code? The Exposed view works with Ajax. Ajax does his job, when I look in firebugg, he generates everything (I think so) but the filter option still doesn't work. I see al my products on the page, the block and I see the view, but the filter option didn't do his job I think. When I filter on "Holland" he does nothing in my own theme (still see all products) but when I'm used a default theme is see all product with "Holland". The site is 99% done, so I won't change the hole template for it.

Anybody here that knows the solution?

Answer (score 0):

> have you include 
>   **$scripts** and **$closure** in your page.tpl.php?